# Need to access the data for countQuery

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, pagination

i am using spring jpa with pagination, as my backend application.
i have to provide the information to my front-end, including total number of entries.

using native query.

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
  @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM USERS",
    countQuery = "SELECT count(*) FROM USERS",
    nativeQuery = true)
  List<User> fetchData(Pageable pageable);
}
```

Question: i wish to access the data for nativeQuery so that i can return same as header of response object, how shall i achieve it?

for count currently i am relying to hitting another query to fetch the information.
But the approach causing me hitting DB 2 times minimum.

i expect to get the data while call one method only.